# cannot access Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I've installed a fresh version of ruby and RoR on a Win XP. I run WEBRick server and everything seems Ok but I can not access `http://0.0.0.0:3000` from the browser. I've tried to change the port to 80 but still have the same problem, even ping gives a "cannot find host" error. Any clue guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `http://localhost:3000`, that should work.

Comment: @Ans 0.0.0.0 is not a valid loopback address. This is simply a configuration idiom that means "listen on all adapters". 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address and localhost is the default alias for it. If you listened on 127.0.0.1 then other computers would not be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` or `http://localhost:3000/` instead?